# Stripping String(Paragraphs) into words using Java

Tags: java, string

Tried using a while loop and str.subtring() but am getting a Heap Space error(assuming it is because the while loop isn't breaking?)

```java
package pckg;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KeywordMatcher 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String s_0 = "apple pie bitch cunt whore ass dick big nib crunch";
        String s_1 = "john stewart ass loser bitch lee dick cook ally die";
        
        System.out.println(keywordsFromString(s_0));
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<String> keywordsFromString(String s)
    {
        ArrayList<String> ans = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        int iter=0;
        while(iter<s.length()) 
        {
            if(s.indexOf(" ") == -1)
            {
                break;
            }
            
            if(iter == 0) 
            {
                ans.add(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")));
            }
            else 
            {
                s = s.substring(iter+1,s.length());
                ans.add(s.substring(iter+1,s.indexOf(" ")));
                iter = s.indexOf(" ");
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir you should also add a check to see if iterator is less than the size of the string.  Also consider using Scanner.  Lastly, nice test data strings :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get, what you exactly want to achieve with your code, but you created an endless loop that only adds the first word of your input string to an `ArrayList`:

You initialize `iter = 0;`.
With your input string, the first `if` is not exiting the loop, because the input contains a space.
The condition of the second `if` is true, because `iter == 0` from the initialization. You add the first word to the list.
But then, you don't modify the value of `iter`, and so the loop goes on endless with `iter == 0`.

The whole body inside the loop will never work as intended, because your split into "handle the first word" and "other words" does not really work out properly.

I would recommend this much simpler implementation that makes use of a very simple regular expression and a built in method of `String`:

```java
public static List<String> keywordsFromString(String s) {
    String[] resultArray = s.split(" ");
    List<String> unmodifiableList = Arrays.asList(resultArray)
    List<String> modifiableList = new ArrayList<>(unmodifiableList);
    return modifiableList
}
```

I artificially split it up to several lines to make it easier understandable.
You also should not return an `ArrayList` because it is very likely that you will not need to know that implementation detail outside your method.

`String.split` splits the string into an array by a regular expression - in your case it is the same as if it were a plain delimiter, but for other expressions it could be trickier, so you have to take care a bit, especially when it comes to things like `.`, `(`, `[` and so on.

If you don't need to modify the resulting list later, you could simply return the result of `Arrays.asList` directly. The use of `List<String>` as return type instead of `ArrayList` makes this possible.

Comment: Oh that's what i was looking to do. Shoul'dve just used String.split() thanks